# MS Access conditional formatting on all records

Tags: ms-access, formatting

Does anyone know of a method to make MS Access evaluate all conditional formatting for all records in a form view?

The problem is that when the user scrolls with the scroll bar, no colors are added (conditional formatting is not evaluated) before the user releases the scroll bar. The thing is, if I scroll down, forcing all records to be evaluated in the formatting, Access seems to remember the formatting. So, hopefully there is a way to evaluate them all on load.

Example of evaluated cells with blue background:
[image]

First, i hold down the scroll bar.
[image]

Secondly, i "release" the scroll bar.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @ErikvonAsmuth, it's not the same issue, unfortunately. The speed is fine in my sheet, it just doesnt update records outside the "view".

Comment: The issue might not be the same, but the solution is. View and implement that solution.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth See new screen dumps. The last picture is condition settings.

Comment: I'm afraid this is Access limitation, you cannot see conditional formatting until you release the scrollbar. Implementation of multi-threading in Access is awful unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, I retracted my close vote. I believe this is just normal behaviour (the cells not coloring when holding down the scroll bar) and nothing can be done, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. Controls show conditional formatting when form opens and still display correctly when scrolling but this is a very small dataset.

Comment: @June7 Do you scroll with the scroller wheel on the mouse or by dragging the scroll bar with the cursor?

Comment: Tested both methods.

Comment: Hmm, thats a pitty. It gives quite poor user experience - So im told...